# Opening Bluetooth Settings Page (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm trying to get the functionality of the android `Settings` class in my flutter app. Using the `app_settings` package for this. I'm using the `AppSettings.openBluetoothSettings();` function, and instead of taking me to the `Bluetooth` page where I can enable or disable the bluetooth, it takes me to the connected devices page.

I checked kotlin part of the package and saw this:

```
openSettings(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS, asAnotherTask)
```

This code somehow works differently depending on the Android version. When I test it in Android 9, it works as expected. However, with Android 12, it sends me the "Connected Devices" page.